# Accessing Parameters from the Main Data Source from A Secondary Dataset

Tags: charts, dataset, jasper-reports

I've got a chart that uses a secondary dataset. It allows for the use of the fields and parameters of the second dataset, however I'm not able to use the parameters set in the main report dataset. Does anyone have any clue how to access the values of the parameters?

For example 
I have the following parameters in the main dataset:

```
 valueOne
 valueTwo
```

And a secondary data set:

```
  fieldOne, fieldTwo
```

From the chart that is set to use the second dataset, how would I request parameter: "valueOne"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter to your subDataset that has the exact same name as the parameter in the main dataset. Leave the default value expression blank and do not prompt for a value. When you reference the parameter in the subdataset, the value from the main dataset will be returned.

So in your case monksy, you should add an empty parameter named "valueOne" to your second dataset.

I've never seen this behaviour documented anywhere; I found it out by accident when working on a report.

Comment: Nope, for real. Thinking about it I'm not sure whether it's a feature or a bug.

Comment: From my experience, thats a bug. That kind of dualism hurts my head.

Comment: When I do that I get a null coming from the second parameter with the same name.